# Pow is not working for two double digit numbers

Tags: c

I have made a code to read two long integers (A and B) from standard input and output (to standard output) A to the power of B.

It works for 1^some huge number, 3^3 etc.

But not for 13^16.

I've tried to put long int ans to solve it, it gave me a different value but not the right one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int x, n;
    long int ans;
    scanf("%d \n %d",&x, &n);

    ans = pow(x,n);

    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `long long` instead, that should be big enough to hold the result. Also note that you will have to adjust the format specifier in the `printf` call. It's `%ld` for `long` and `%lld` for `long long`.

Comment: *"I've tried to put long int ans to solve it, it gave me a different value but not the right one."* So what was it? What was the value you expected? Please [edit] your question and include *all* necessary information.

Comment: `pow` does not work with integers very well. Use `double` instead.

Comment: The value of 13^16 is 665416609183179841. The maximum value of a 32-bit `long` is 2^31-1, or 2147483647. The maximum value of a 64-bit `long long` is 9223372036854775807. Choose wisely.

Comment: Even `long long` will not work for *all* 2-digit values of base and power. You'll need to write it yourself, or use a big integer library.

Comment: `pow()` probably will not give the precise answer for 13^16 anyway, but `powl()` might do.  The `double` result of `pow()` is good for only about 15 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: The first chapters of a C programming book usually addresses the maximum values of types. Good stuff worth reading.

Comment: @WeatherVane `long long` won't even work for `pow(13, 16)` because the precision of `double` isn't enough.

Comment: " code to read two long integers (A and B)" --> code does not do that. `int x, n;
    scanf("%d \n %d",&x, &n)` reads 2 `int`, not `long`.

Comment: Try `printf("%Lf\n", powl(x,n));`

Answer (score 2):

`pow(1,anything)` is always 1. `pow(3, 3)` is 27. These are both quite small numbers and easily fit into a 32 bit integer. `pow(13,16)` is (approximately) 6.65 x 10<sup>17</sup>. This is too big for a 32 bit integer to contain. It will go into a 64 bit integer (although `pow(14, 17)` will not). It's likely that your compiler treats a `long` as a 32 bit value, which is not uncommon. You could try `long long` which is likely to be 64 bits or `int64_t` which is explicitly 64 bits long.

Note though that the prototype for `pow()` is

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

which means that it is returning a double precision floating point number and then coercing it into the type of your variable. `double` (a 64 bit floating point number) only has 53 bits of precision in its mantissa, which means you are not going to get the exact number when you cast it back to even a 64 bit integer. You could use `powl()` whose prototype is

```
long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```

But `long double` might be defined as 80 bits or 128 bits or even only 64 bits (Microsoft). It might give you the precision you need, but such is the nature of power operations, your input numbers won't have to get much bigger to overflow the precision of even the longest `long double`.

If you really need to raise large numbers to large powers, you are going to need a big integer library.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined "ans" as long int  then you are trying to print it as int (%d - Take the next argument and print it as an int ) So change `printf("%d", ans)` to `printf("%ld",ans)` . your code would look something like this :

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <math.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x, n;
        long int ans;
        scanf("%d \n %d",&x, &n);

        ans = pow(x,n);

        printf("%ld", ans);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use floating point `pow()`  and friends with their potential limited precision for an integer problem within 64 bits (13<sup>16</sup> needs 60 bits), use an integer power function.

```
unsigned long long upow(unsigned  x, unsigned y) {
  unsigned long long z = 1;
  unsigned long long xx = x;
  while (y) {
    if (y % 2) {
      z *= xx;
    }
    y /= 2;
    xx *= xx;
  }
  return z;
}

int main() {
  printf("%llu\n", upow(3, 3));
  printf("%llu\n", upow(13, 16));
}
```

Output

```
27
665416609183179841
```

If code needs to handle answers more the 64 bits, consider `long double` (with potential loss of precision)  or big_integer libraries.